# Wakanda Datastore - Find and Replace?

Tags: wakanda

I've got a lot of values in a legacy Wakanda datastore which I need to update to some new values. Is there a curl-like command in the wakanda data browser page that can be used to do a mass find-and-replace in a table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your dataclass is called `MyDataClass` and the attribute you want to update is `myAttribute` you can use the following server-side script :

```
    var newValue = "new value";

    ds.MyDataClass.all().forEach(function(entity){
            entity.myAttribute = newValue;
            entity.save();
    });
```

You can also use a [transaction](http://doc.wakanda.org/home2.en.html#/Datastore/Transactions.201-594705.en.html) if you want to commit or rollback the whole operation

Comment: Thanks, this came in very handy!

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a way to do a mass of find/replace in the dataBrowser,
But I suggest you to use a query in the server side that search the records with the value you need to replace, and then a loop on this collection to set the new values

Comment: I'll do some digging to find the correct syntax for querying the db server side. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in other answers, you are likely best to loop over a collection. There is no concept of a mass replace in Wakanda like you see in many other databases.

```
var myCollection = ds.DataClassName.query("attributeName == :1", "valueToFind");
myCollection.forEach(function(e){
    e.attributeName = "newValue";
    e.save();
});
```

So a fake "person" data type might look like this:

```
var blankFirsts = ds.Person.query("firstname == :1", "");
blankFirsts.forEach(function(person){
    person.firstname = "no name";
    person.save();
});
```